# How to update data in dataGridView not using SQL query

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to make a CRUD operation in dataGridView not using SQL query just use dataSet. `delete` and
`create` functions are ok but I'm stuck on how to implement a `update`.

The requirement is when the user click on data cell in dataGridView then all of data of that cell
will display in a list of already created `textBoxes`, and can edit or update those data. All of the field's data can be changed but the `id` of the row must be unchanged.

My idea is to use a `dataGridView_CellContentClick` when I click on the cell. All of the data will be display in an already-created list of `textboxes`. We need to get the `id` of the row we want to edit by using a class member variable to store it in. But in the final step I don't know how to assign updated data to the row of dataGridView. Does anyone have any solution for that?

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // data set 
        DataSet1 dSet;
        // to get id of current row
        int id;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PersonInfoInit();
        }

        // udpate cell clicked data 
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // get id of the row want to update
            id = dtgView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            UpdateData();
        }

        // update current cell clicked data helper function 
        private void UpdateData()
        {
            if (dtgView.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                txtAge.Text = dtgView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                txtName.Text = dtgView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                txtEmail.Text = dtgView.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void PersonInfoInit()
        {
            dSet = new DataSet1();

            dSet.Tables["Person"].Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Kane", 23, "abc@gmail.com" });
            dSet.Tables["Person"].Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Sam", 22, "abc@gmail.com"});
            dSet.Tables["Person"].Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Hung", 24, "haha@naver" });
            dSet.Tables["Person"].Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Tuan", 26, "blusPai@hanmail"});

            dtgView.AutoGenerateColumns = true; // without this line, datatGridView will not display data
            dtgView.DataSource = dSet.Tables["Person"];
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dSet.Tables["Person"].Rows.Add(new object[]
            {
                dSet.Tables["Person"].Rows.Count + 1, int.Parse(txtAge.Text), txtName.Text.Trim(), txtEmail.Text.Trim()
            });

            ClearText();
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // how can I assign updated data for the row? not Add newly
            // dSet.Tables["Person"].Rows[id]. = new object[] {
                
            // };
        }

        // delete current clicked cell data 
        private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dtgView.SelectedCells)
                {
                    if (cell.Selected)
                        dtgView.Rows.RemoveAt(cell.RowIndex);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: can't remve this data");
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Removed data successfully.");
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to let the user make changes “directly” in the grid cells? Is there some special data validation needed?

Comment: Just use a BindingSource, use it as the DataSource of your DGW and add DataBindings to the TextBoxes using the same BindingSource. When you click on a Cell, you also change the `Current` reference: your TextBox Control will reflect the current DataRow and any change in the TextBox text automatically updates the source of data.

Comment: @JohnG Could you give me some more details about "make change directly" in the grid cell? No there is no need fore data validation.

Comment: @Jimi I'm not sure I can understand your idea, could you provide some snippets using BindingSource on dataGridView?

Comment: After the grid is loaded with data, you should be able to simply click into a cell and type what you want. Obviously, if the cell is a numeric cell you may want to allow only numbers to avoid an error. However, if the cell is a “text” cell, technically you should be able to type anything into the cell. These changes will automatically be reflected in the grids data source. I fell like I am missing something.

Comment: `BindingSource dsetSource = null; DataSet1 dSet = null; [...] dSet = new DataSet1(); [...] dsetSource = new BindingSource(dSet, "Person"); dtgView.DataSource = dsetSource;` -- What is a `DataSet1`? Why don't you have a `DataSet` Type?

Comment: @JohnG I'm not sure but having that said you mean set `dataGridView.readOnly = false` ? Then user can directly changed existing data on the by clicking on it and edit?

Comment: @Jimi `DataSet` is added from the toolBox and I defined the table `Person` and column at that time as well.

Comment: If you dropped a (Typed? UnTyped?) DataSet as a Component, why are you trying to create a new instance of it? That's an Instance object, not a Type. You cannot create a new instance of it, as you cannot create a new Instance of, e.g., `Button1`. You can create a new Instance of a `Button` Type. Or a `DataSet` Type.

Comment: If you want only certain columns to be editable… then do NOT set the whole grid to read only. After the data is loaded into the grid... set the “columns” you do not want the user to edit to read only. Example, If there is an ID column the user shouldn’t edit… then make that single COLUMN read only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a dataset you could use a BindingList of person objects and just add, delete or modify the objects in that list.

```
private BindingList<Person> Persons = new BindingList<Person>();
....
  private void PersonInfoInit()
    {
      this.Persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Kane", Age = 23, Email = "abc@gmail.com" });
      this.Persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "Sam", Age = 2, Email = "abc@gmail.com" });

      this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
      this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.Persons;
    }

...
    public class Person
    {

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }

      public int Age { get; set; }

      public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```